# Getting a user country name from originating IP address with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip-geolocation

I want to extract a user country name from visitors' IP addresses.

I could get the IP address with `remote_ip`. But what could be
the easiest way to get the country name?

It doesn't have to be super accurate. Any ruby library (gem or plugin) to do this?

I want an simple and easy solution for this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `geoip` gem.

environment.rb

```
config.gem 'geoip'
```

Download `GeoIP.dat.gz` from `http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry`. unzip the file. The below assumes under `#{RAILS_ROOT}/db` dir.

```
@geoip ||= GeoIP.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/db/GeoIP.dat")    
remote_ip = request.remote_ip 
if remote_ip != "127.0.0.1" #todo: check for other local addresses or set default value
  location_location = @geoip.country(remote_ip)
  if location_location != nil     
    @model.country = location_location[2]
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like they changed the format of that file because if the full name is what you want, location_location[5] is the way to go.

Comment: Actually, from geoip 1.1.1, you can user @geoip.country(ip).country_name

Comment: geoip is now out of date; see my answer.

Answer (score 35):

You can also use "[Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/)"

It will just make you life easier. Put the following line in your Gemfile and issue the bundle install command

```
gem 'geocoder'
```

Using this Gem, you can easily get the country, ip or even city of the originating IP. See an example below

```
request.ip  # =>    "182.185.141.75"
request.location.city   # =>    ""
request.location.country    # =>    "Pakistan"
```

Comment: Is there a limit with this gem? What type of provider you use with this gem? I have understood that there are limitations of 2500 request per day. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!. The documentation is a bit confusing.

Comment: @hyperrjas yes if you're using Google's API you can checkout the the quota per each provider from this link https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#listing-and-comparison

Answer (score 11):

I'm using this one-liner:

```
locale = Timeout::timeout(5) { Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' + request.remote_ip )).body } rescue "US"
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot! I have also added something like `locale = 'US' if locale == 'XX'`. In some cases api.hostip.info returned `XX`, so I am catching that as well.

Comment: Looking back at this, there is the danger of that service timing out, so you should probably put this onto an asynchronous call and send it back to the browser via a websocket or by polling. And cache the result in something like memcache or redis.

Comment: Just tested with my IP and It gives a wrong result.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest is to use an existing web service for this.

There are plugins that let you do much more, including making your models geolocation-aware (geokit-rails) automatically, but if all you need is a country code for example, simply sending an HTTP Get to `http://api.hostip.info/country.php` (there are other services  but this one does not require an API key) will return it, e.g. :

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://api.hostip.info/country.php'))
=> US
```

Or polling http://api.hostip.info/ will return a full XML response with city, latitude, longitude, etc.

Be aware that the results you get are not 100% accurate. For example, right now I'm in France but reported as in Germany. This will be the case for pretty much any IP-based service.

Comment: You can pass the IP address of the visiting user to this API as a parameter http://api.hostip.info/?ip=217.132.3.54 which means you can do Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' + request.remote_ip )) (Not sure why that ; character is appearing and I can't get rid of it)

Comment: Yeah this seems like the simplest option. Another API you could use is http://ipinfo.io, which will return full JSON details if you request just that, or you can get just the country string with http://ipinfo.io/country

Comment: @BenDowling  +1 for [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/) - I just tested a dozen real-world examples and hostip.info failed most while ipinfo.io didn't miss. Very reasonable prices/rate limits too.

Answer (score 6):

The `geoip` gem no longer works with the new MaxMind databases. There is a new gem that does this, [MaxMind-DB-Reader-ruby](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-ruby).

Simply download the City or Country binary, gzipped databases from [MaxMind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/), unzip, and use the following sort of code:

```
require 'maxmind/db'

reader = MaxMind::DB.new('GeoIP2-City.mmdb', mode: MaxMind::DB::MODE_MEMORY)

# you probably want to replace 1.1.1.1 with  request.remote_ip
# or request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
ip_addr = '1.1.1.1'
record = reader.get(ip_addr)
if record.nil?
  puts '#{ip_addr} was not found in the database'
else
  puts record['country']['iso_code']
  puts record['country']['names']['en']
end

reader.close
```

Adapt based on your needs. I created a method in an initializer which I can call as necessary.

Comment: This is the Maxmind official gem / repo for their stuff, so the database should stay current as well, thanks Artelius :)

Answer (score 5):

One service you could use to do this is my own, https://ipinfo.io. It gives you country code and a bunch of other details:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "24.6.61.239",
  "hostname": "c-24-6-61-239.hsd1.ca.comcast.net",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3845,-122.0881",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, LLC",
  "postal": "94040"
}
```

If you just want the country you can get that by requesting `/country`

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/country
US
```

You can then map from a country code to a name using the data from http://country.io, or using the example at http://ipinfo.io/developers/full-country-names

Comment: `%x(curl 'ipinfo.io/country')` is the right code to use. Does it return the server's country or the client's country? Are there quota limits or other limitations to respect?

Comment: If you're calling it from the server it'll return the server's IP - you need to pass in the client's IP. See https://ipinfo.io/developers

Answer (score 2):

I've just published a gem for the [IPLocate.io API](https://www.iplocate.io) which I created.

Super easy, no databases to download, and 1,500 free requests per day:

```
require 'iplocate'

# Look up an IP address
results = IPLocate.lookup("8.8.8.8")

# Or with an API key
results = IPLocate.lookup("8.8.8.8", "abcdef")

results["country"]
# "United States"

results["country_code"]
# "US"

results["org"]
# "Google LLC"

results.inspect
# {
#   "ip"=>"8.8.8.8",
#   "country"=>"United States",
#   "country_code"=>"US",
#   "city"=>nil,
#   "continent"=>"North America",
#   "latitude"=>37.751,
#   "longitude"=>-97.822,
#   "time_zone"=>nil,
#   "postal_code"=>nil,
#   "org"=>"Google LLC",
#   "asn"=>"AS15169"
# }
```

### No Gem

It can also be used without a gem by just using Ruby's `Net::HTTP` and `URI`:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( "https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8" ) )
```

The request will return JSON so you can parse it and access it as follows:

```
country = JSON.parse( response )["country"]
# => "US"
```

Comment: Great little service! Hooked it up in Ruby without needing to even download the gem. Just do a Net::HTTP request with `JSON.parse( Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( "https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/139.18.2.74" ) ) )`

Comment: @ttarik when I run your code I get the error: `require': cannot load such file -- ip
address (LoadError)....I downloaded the iplocate gem. Do you have a possible solution to this?

Comment: @tee Sounds like it can't find the gem. Have you added `iplocate` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`? Or, you can use the 'No Gem' code example helpfully posted by Joshua :)

Comment: @ttarik I added the gem and still get the error...it's all good though I can use the 'No Gem' code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Yandex locator gem](https://github.com/sergey-chechaev/yandex_locator), service returns longitude, latitude and precision.

```
conn = YandexLocator::Client.new
result = conn.lookup(ip: "109.252.52.39")
# => {"position"=>{"altitude"=>0.0, "altitude_precision"=>30.0, "latitude"=>55.75395965576172, "longitude"=>37.62039184570312, "precision"=>100000.0, "type"=>"ip"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Ruby example calling the [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-1988049&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) API.

It's fast and has reliable performance thanks to having 10 global endpoints each able to handle >10,000 requests per second!

> This answer uses a 'test' API Key that is very limited and only meant for testing a few calls. [Signup](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-1988049-free-plan-cta&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) for your own Free API Key and get up to 1500 requests daily for development.

Replace `78.8.53.5` with any ip you want to look up

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
require 'rest_client'

headers = {
  :accept => 'application/json'
}

response = RestClient.get 'https://api.ipdata.co/78.8.53.5?api-key=test', headers
puts response
```

That'd give you

```
{
    "ip": "78.8.53.5",
    "is_eu": true,
    "city": "G\u0142og\u00f3w",
    "region": "Lower Silesia",
    "region_code": "DS",
    "country_name": "Poland",
    "country_code": "PL",
    "continent_name": "Europe",
    "continent_code": "EU",
    "latitude": 51.6557,
    "longitude": 16.089,
    "asn": "AS12741",
    "organisation": "Netia SA",
    "postal": "67-200",
    "calling_code": "48",
    "flag": "https://ipdata.co/flags/pl.png",
    "emoji_flag": "\ud83c\uddf5\ud83c\uddf1",
    "emoji_unicode": "U+1F1F5 U+1F1F1",
    "carrier": {
        "name": "Netia",
        "mcc": "260",
        "mnc": "07"
    },
    "languages": [
        {
            "name": "Polish",
            "native": "Polski"
        }
    ],
    "currency": {
        "name": "Polish Zloty",
        "code": "PLN",
        "symbol": "z\u0142",
        "native": "z\u0142",
        "plural": "Polish zlotys"
    },
    "time_zone": {
        "name": "Europe/Warsaw",
        "abbr": "CEST",
        "offset": "+0200",
        "is_dst": true,
        "current_time": "2018-08-29T15:34:23.518065+02:00"
    },
    "threat": {
        "is_tor": false,
        "is_proxy": false,
        "is_anonymous": false,
        "is_known_attacker": false,
        "is_known_abuser": false,
        "is_threat": false,
        "is_bogon": false
    },
}
```

Comment: when I run the above code I get the error: "`require': cannot load such file -- rest_client (LoadError)"....From where can I access the rest_client file

Answer (score 1):

Try the IP2Location Ruby

https://github.com/ip2location/ip2location-ruby

## Pre-requisite

Download the free LITE database from http://lite.ip2location.com/ and use below.

## Install

```
gem install ip2location_ruby
```

## Usage

```
require 'ip2location_ruby'

i2l = Ip2location.new.open("./data/IP-COUNTRY-SAMPLE.BIN")
record = i2l.get_all('8.8.8.8')

print 'Country Code: ' + record.country_short + "\n"
print 'Country Name: ' + record.country_long + "\n"
print 'Region Name: ' + record.region + "\n"
print 'City Name: ' + record.city + "\n"
print 'Latitude: '
print record.latitude
print "\n"
print 'Longitude: '
print record.longitude
print "\n"
print 'ISP: ' + record.isp + "\n"
print 'Domain: ' + record.domain + "\n"
print 'Net Speed: ' + record.netspeed + "\n"
print 'Area Code: ' + record.areacode + "\n"
print 'IDD Code: ' + record.iddcode + "\n"
print 'Time Zone: ' + record.timezone + "\n"
print 'ZIP Code: ' + record.zipcode + "\n"
print 'Weather Station Code: ' + record.weatherstationname + "\n"
print 'Weather Station Name: ' + record.weatherstationcode + "\n"
print 'MCC: ' + record.mcc + "\n"
print 'MNC: ' + record.mnc + "\n"
print 'Mobile Name: ' + record.mobilebrand + "\n"
print 'Elevation: '
print record.elevation
print "\n"
print 'Usage Type: ' + record.usagetype + "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

The gem [`geoip`](https://github.com/cjheath/geoip) can be replaced with the new gem [`maxminddb`](https://github.com/yhirose/maxminddb). It support new MaxMind db format.

```rb
db = MaxMindDB.new('./GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
ret = db.lookup('74.125.225.224')

ret.found? # => true
ret.country.name # => 'United States'
ret.country.name('zh-CN') # => '美国'
ret.country.iso_code # => 'US'
ret.city.name(:fr) # => 'Mountain View'
ret.subdivisions.most_specific.name # => 'California'
ret.location.latitude # => -122.0574
```