# Extracting IP address, webbrowser's description, country from a HTTP request

Tags: jakarta-ee, browser, ip-address, country

I'm trying to develop a webapp that can extract the IP address, the webbrowser's description and the country of the enduser's request.

But I can't find how to deal that. How can I do this, please ?

Answer (score 1):

This information is provided by `javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest`:

- IP address: `request.getRemoteAddr()`
- Web browser description (the "user agent"): `request.getHeader("user-agent")`

---

There is normally no country information, so you have to use a geolocation service together with the IP address.

For example http://freegeoip.net: Use an URL like

`http://freegeoip.net/xml/www.stackoverflow.com`

Other formats (CSV, JSON) are possible, it's described on their home page.

Possibly helpful:

- `request.getHeader("accept-language")`: Contains a list of languages (like "en", "de", "fr", ...)

---

Note: There is always the IP address, but request headers are optional.

Comment: That's interesting, but, how can I include this in my java code knowing that I need to get the enduser's country not the of a web site ? There is any documentations about that please ?

Comment: That's interesting, but, how can I include this in my java code knowing that I need to get the enduser's country not of a web site ? There is any documentations about that please ?

Comment: Just use the value from `request.getRemoteAddr()` as the argument in the URL for freegeoip.

Comment: I've tested your suggestion in localhost, but, I've got this `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` as IP, `fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4` as language, `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36` as a webbrowser's description knowing that I'm running it with Chrome. So I've got an error when I've tried to read the XML file as i've a wrong ip adress.

Comment: Of course you cannot "locate" a localhost IP address. Just try it with a real public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of info on this available.  Much depends on what you are running on the server:
[How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript),
[Getting a user country name from originating IP address with Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988049/getting-a-user-country-name-from-originating-ip-address-with-ruby-on-rails)