# Need country name from the request or with ip_address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ip, ip-address

I have already search out on the stack overflow but didn't find any answered related to it.

With the following below line we can get the ip address of request.

```
request.remote_ip
```

it's working fine for the ip address and gives me correct ip address of the remote machine.

But for the location it doesn't gives me the correct location.

```
request.location
```

With the above line the data which i get is like below

```
#<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0xb47eae8c @data={"ip"=>"192.168.1.183", "country_code"=>"RD", "country_name"=>"Reserved", "region_code"=>"", "region_name"=>"", "city"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "latitude"=>0, "longitude"=>0, "metro_code"=>"", "areacode"=>""}, @cache_hit=nil>
```

But the ip address is currently in india and it gives me the country name "Reserved"

Any one help will defiantly appreciate

Comment: here you are using a class C IP address, LAN ip address, hence it might be giving reserved country code

Comment: So what should i give can you please suggest me to get correct country name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby programmer, PHP instead.  But I doubt Ruby has an innate way to know what country an IP address is located.  Try the API from a site like this: http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm

Answer (score 1):

use `geoip` gem,

visit this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988049/getting-a-user-country-name-from-originating-ip-address-with-ruby-on-rails) for more and detailed answers.

If you do not want to use gem then use following simple code:--

```
require 'net/http'

 locale = Timeout::timeout(5) { Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('api.hostip.info/country.php?ip='; + request.remote_ip )).body } rescue "US"
```

Comment: Ya i already try it but it gives me that no .dat file find in your PC.

Comment: Use this locale = Timeout::timeout(5) { Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' + request.remote_ip )).body } rescue "US"

it reurn "IN" when I used my IP address

Comment: You can know your IP address, it might start with 122.xxx.xxx.xxx, use that

Comment: I used my IP and got "IN" in response

1.9.2-p320 :005 > locale = Timeout::timeout(5) { Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' + '124.xxx.xxx.xxx' )).body } rescue "US"
 => "IN"

Comment: Connection refused - connect(2)

Comment: do you know what is your IP address??

Comment: Yes, i know very well my ip address

Comment: are you using following code??

require 'net/http'

locale = Timeout::timeout(5) { Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('api.hostip.info/country.php?ip='; + '124.xxx.xxx.xxx' )).body } rescue "US"

Comment: yes 'XX' for lan IP, go to google and just search "what is my Ip address", it willl give your IP address, use that Ip address in that above code, it will return you "IN" in response.

Comment: then request.remote_ip is not giving the actual ip address of request.

Comment: for development environment it will return LAN class C Ip starting with 192, this is not country specific, you know :)

Comment: if you deploy your app, then it will return real country code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the sample code that you may refer to.

[Retreive the geolocation of an IP address using Ruby](https://github.com/jeroenj/geo_ip)