# How to find the Client country from the Rails TCP server is getting use in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tcp, rubygems, tcpclient

I am using Rails 5 with ruby 2.4
I am using TCP server for the TCP api communication. I am able to find the Ip address from which the request is getting generated like:

```
    require 'socket'
    server = TCPServer.new 53492 # Server bound to port 53492
        loop do
          Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
            p "Client peer address = #{client.peeraddr[3]}"
         end
       end
```

Can I get the country form which the request client is using the Api.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988049/getting-a-user-country-name-from-originating-ip-address-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2):

This is called geolocating. Just google "ruby geolocation" and you will find gems and resources. Here are a couple that are able to convert an IP address into a geolocation:

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder
https://github.com/geokit/geokit

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder
Included gem in gemfile:

```
 gem 'geocoder'
```

in the code:

```
   results = Geocoder.search(remote_ip)
   country = results.first.country
```